# SQL EXISTS vs. Aggregate IS NOT NULL

Tags: sql, database, db2, aggregate, exists

I have two different forms of SQL condition clauses.

Using EXISTS:

```
exists (select 1 from [table] where [conditions])
```

Using Aggregate function:

```
(select max(1) from [table] where [conditions]) is not null
```

[table] and [conditions] are equal in both statements.
Is there a possibility these two clauses will return different results?
If not, which one has better query performance?
If it matters, the database in question is IBM DB2 UDB v10.

Comment: Does IBM DB2 UDB v10 have an EXPLAIN statement?

Comment: There's no such thing as DB2 UDB v10.

Comment: Yes there is EXPLAIN. I don't have privilege to use it however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have DB2 to test this on.  But I think it depends.  The following statement:

```
select max(1)
from (select 1 as i)t
where i = 2
```

Produces different results on SQL Server (`null`) and MySQL (1).  If DB2 returns `1`, then the statements are different.  I would expect it to return `null`, though.

If it returns `null`, then the two statements are the same in effect.  However, the `max()` statement is likely to perform less well than the `exists`.  The `exists` statement can stop at the first matching value.

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff. It returned `null`. Thanks again for the explanation on speed.